# Why doesn't visual rumble work?

Tags: epsxe

I'm using ePSXe 1.7.0, Pete's OpenGL2 Driver 2.9 (changelog says it supports visual rumble) and the default gamepad plugin. I've chosen to emulate a DualShock gamepad and the Rumble setting is set to Visual, yet I see no visual rumble. How can I get visual rumble to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must start the game normally instead of loading a save state to make visual rumble work. The game remembers if the controller is rumble-enabled, so you need to restart the game to make it recheck. After you have done so, you may make new save states and visual rumble will work if loading them.